# subfig package in latex

Tags: latex

When I am using subfig package in latex, it gives some errors:

```
Package subfig Warning: Your document class has a bad definition  
 of \endfigure, most likely  
 \let\endfigure=\end@float  
 which has now been changed to  
 \def\endfigure{\end@float}  
 because otherwise subsequent changes to \end@float  
 (like done by several packages changing float behaviour)  
 can't take effect on \endfigure.  
 Please complain to your document class author.  


Package subfig Warning: Your document class has a bad definition  
 of \endtable, most likely  
 \let\endtable=\end@float  
 which has now been changed to  
 \def\endtable{\end@float}  
 because otherwise subsequent changes to \end@float  
 (like done by several packages changing float behaviour)  
 can't take effect on \endtable.  
 Please complain to your document class author.  

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty  
         `rotating' package detected  
         `float' package detected  
)   

LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 139, version  
               `2005/06/26' of package caption,  
               but only version  
               `1995/04/05 v1.4b caption package (AS)'  
               is available.  

! Undefined control sequence.  
l.163 \DeclareCaptionOption  
                           {listofformat}{\caption@setlistofformat{#1}}
```

How can I solve it?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: when reporting problems with latex, the error log is usually not necessary. Please provide the code you are using, with packages not related to the problem commented out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a clash between subfig and an old version of the caption package. Try updating your caption package to something more recent. In general, it is a good idea to keep all packages updated to their latest versions.